# intbitset __init__ causes SIGSEGV

Tags: python

The following code causes a segmentation fault to be raised. I'm not really sure why...

```
import numpy as np
from intbitset import intbitset

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# This works
intbitset(arr.tolist())
=> intbitset([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# This throws SIGSEGV
intbitset([x for x in arr])
```

`[x for x in arr]` works perfectly and returns the list as expected.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Doesn't the list comprehension get evaluated to a list before entering `intbitset` ctr?

I've tested on both Python 3.6.3 and 2.7.13 (need to change `zip` to `itertools.izip`). Crashes on both. `intbitset` version is 2.3.0

Comment: Reproducible on Arch Linux, Python 3.6.4. Funnily, it does work with a generator, if you remove the `[]`. But it does not work with a generic iterable like passing `arr` itself (though no segfault in that case).

Comment: @Thomas - It doesn't crash but doesn't really work. it gets you an empty bitset. But that's probably because the package doesn't support generators.

Comment: I see you have [opened a bug against intbitset](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/intbitset/issues/60). I think that's the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something interesting:

```
$ gdb python 
...
(gdb) run crash.py
...
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff745338b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff745338b in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#1  0x00007ffff74a245f in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#2  0x00007ffff73f0565 in PyList_Append ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#3  0x00007ffff73a2580 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff7404b55 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#5  0x00007ffff740e10f in _PyObject_FastCallDict ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#6  0x00007ffff73fc9d0 in PyFile_WriteObject ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff74a3d6a in PyFile_WriteString ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff74b2f9d in PyTraceBack_Print ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#9  0x00007ffff7491154 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#10 0x00007ffff7327d14 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#11 0x00007ffff749136e in PyErr_Display ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#12 0x00007ffff74c890a in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#13 0x00007ffff7404ad0 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#14 0x00007ffff740e10f in _PyObject_FastCallDict ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#15 0x00007ffff7492c5b in PyErr_PrintEx ()
  3.6m.so.1.0
#16 0x00007ffff74939d1 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#17 0x00007ffff748970b in Py_Main ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#18 0x0000555555554c39 in main ()
```

Observe the calls to `PyErr_Display` and `PyTraceBack_Print`. It looks like Python tried to show an error, but crashed in the process. Indeed, this does not crash:

```
try:
    intbitset([x for x in arr])
except Exception as ex:
    print(repr(ex))
```

Rather, it outputs the following:

```
ValueError('retrieving integers from rhs is impossible: invalid index to scalar variable.')
```

This exception is raised [here in `intbitset.__cinit__`](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/intbitset/blob/8bdb3771f125495eb32a1a7c0690d57e346dc800/intbitset/intbitset.pyx#L249). Note that [`__cinit__`](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html) is a special Cython function.

It is raised in response to another exception, coming from [`gen_arrtype_subscript`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1290e7fd5d40903d69733b4797f7c30ca025e1f7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L3572) in numpy C code. It can be triggered by indexing a scalar like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> arr[0][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

The reason that `intbitset` triggers this exception is [this line](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/intbitset/blob/8bdb3771f125495eb32a1a7c0690d57e346dc800/intbitset/intbitset.pyx#L177):

```
  tuple_of_tuples = rhs and hasattr(rhs, '__getitem__') and hasattr(rhs[0], '__getitem__')
```

Indeed, numpy scalars (`numpy.int64` in this case) *do* have a `__getitem__`, they just don't like it if you call it. This causes `intbitset` to incorrectly assume that it's receiving a [sequence made of tuples](http://intbitset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#intbitset.intbitset), which triggers the call to the exception-raising `__getitem__`.

This explains why it doesn't crash if you pass a generator, `intbitset(x for x in arr)`: it doesn't have `__getitem__`, so intbitset enters a different code path. If you pass `intbitset(arr)` directly, the `tuple_of_tuples` line triggers another exception, when trying to convert `arr` to a `bool`:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This exception is rather un-Pythonic of numpy (inconsistent with how lists are converted to `bool`), but that's the way it works.

So why does the `invalid index to scalar` exception cause a segfault, even though the `truth value of an array` doesn't? In fact, if I put `raise ValueError()` after it, both end up crashing, so it's clearly Undefined Behaviour going on in both cases, and pure luck that it sometimes doesn't crash.

My guess is that `intbitset` does something unexpected by raising an exception from `__cinit__`. It's not explicitly forbidden in the Cython docs, so I'm not sure how or what.